# Django filter from date to date

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find a way to set a filter on Django Admin for dates using start date and end date, but on the docs the search seems to do a SQL search like so

```
WHERE (first_name ILIKE 'john' OR last_name ILIKE 'john')
AND (first_name ILIKE 'lennon' OR last_name ILIKE 'lennon')
```

Comment: You want to use some custom start and end dates?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing date search you can use the range field look up function.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range

```
Eg. Employee.objects.filter(bday__range=(start_date, end_date))
```